# Colors of image's pixels change when rotating image using java OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

hope you're doing well.
Actually, i'm facing a problem when trying to rotate an image using ***Core.rotate*** Class of OpenCV.
the colors of the image pixels keep changing every time i click the rotation Button.
Can anyone please help me fixing this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

I've tried to change the colors of the image using Imgproc.cvtColor but it didn't work.
This is the code :

`

```
package application;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class SampleController {

    @FXML
    private ImageView myimageview;
    
    @FXML
    private Button showimageButton, rotateButton;

    @FXML
    void rotateButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage image = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(myimageview.getImage(), null);    
        Mat src = BufferedImage2Mat(image);        
        Core.rotate(src, src, Core.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);
        image = Mat2BufferedImage(src);
        try {
            Image converted_image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);
            myimageview.setImage(converted_image);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    
    public Mat BufferedImage2Mat(BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);
        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        return Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    }
    
    static BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat matrix)throws Exception {        
        MatOfByte mob=new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", matrix, mob);
        byte ba[]=mob.toArray();
        BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(ba));
        return bi;
    }
    
    @FXML
    void showimageButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        Image im = new Image("file:///C:\\Users\\poste\\eclipse-workspace\\dragImage\\Images\\temp.jpg");
        myimageview.setImage(im);
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Can you explain how strong the color change is? Because of interpolation, pixels can have minor color changes, especially at edges. You can prevent that by using NN interpolation (nearest neighbor). But if you have dramatic color changes in the whole image this is likely not your problem source.

Comment: Encoding an image as jpg will always decrease the image quality, because jpg is a lossy compression. Try to encode as .png to check if compression is your problem here.